# Comparison of two tables in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'd need to compare two tables in Teradata SQL.

A sample of the two tables is

Table 1

```
User  Date          Ind1    Ind2
12   2010-05-23     Y       N
12   2010-06-23     Y       Y
12   2010-07-23     Y       N
23   2010-04-23     N       N
23   2010-05-23     N       N
23   2010-06-12     Y       N
```

Table 2

```
User  Date          Ind1    Ind2
12   2010-05-23     Y       N
12   2010-06-23     Y       Y
12   2010-07-23     N       N
24   2010-03-22     N       N
23   2010-04-23     N       Y
23   2010-05-23     N       Y
23   2010-06-12     Y       N
```

In this example, `Table 1` differs from `Table 2` because it has not the user `24` and also some values in `Ind1` and `Ind2` have changed. I usually compare data outside Teradata as I am not familiar with the code. Since the tables are very big, I'd like to know if there is a way to compare directly these tables there (for example, using join for users; I'm interested in looking at cases where there are more `Ind1`=Y in Table 1).

Output expected:

```
Table 1 (where Ind1 and Ind2 have at least 1 Y)
    User  Date          Ind1    Ind2
    12   2010-05-23     Y       N
    12   2010-06-23     Y       Y
    12   2010-07-23     Y       N
    23   2010-06-12     Y       N
```

Table 2

```
User  Date          Ind1    Ind2
12   2010-06-23     Y       Y      /* it differs from Ind2 */
12   2010-07-23     N       N      /* it differs from both indicators */
24   2010-03-22     N       N     /* Not included in Table 1 */
23   2010-04-23     N       Y     /* it differs from Ind2 */
23   2010-05-23     N       Y     /* it differs from Ind2 */ 
23   2010-06-12     Y       N     /* it differs from Ind1 */
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: There are several ways to compare tables, depending on your expected result based on EXCEPT [ALL], NOT EXISTS or FULL JOIN.

Comment: In case you might want to have a look, I have opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969965/spot-differences-in-consecutive-values-periods-between-two-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical method for comparing such tables would use `full join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t1.user = t2.user and t1.date = t2.date and
        t1.ind1 = t2.ind1 and t1.ind2 = t2.ind2
where t1.user is null or t2.user is null;
```

This returns the rows that are in each table that are not in the other.  Note:  It doesn't handle duplicate rows very well -- 1 duplicate in one table matches any number in the other table, for instance.

Comment: @Math . . . That is not the question asked here.  You might want to ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st result looks like a simple

```
select *
from table1
where ind1 = 'Y' 
   or ind2 = 'Y'
```

And the 2nd seems to be a set operation:

```
select *
from table2

except

select *
from table1
```

If there are duplicate rows, EXCEPT ALL might be what you want. If there are no duplicates it might still be more efficient than EXCEPT, you should try it.